# Formatting Razor ViewData in Javascript

Tags: javascript, razor, viewdata

So I have been looking through relevant questions and I can't figure out exactly why my script tag is malformed.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var showME = false;
    var showSuffix = "";

    @if (ViewData["showME"] != null && ViewData["showSuffix"] != null)
    {
        <text>
        showME = @(Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["showME"]) ? "true" : "false");
        showSuffix = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["showSuffix "]))';
        </text>
    }
</script>
```

EDIT!
The answer below is correct but I tracked down the malformed part to this line.

```
var videoHelpUrl = @(Url.Action("Index", "Help", new { Id = 46 }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var videoHelpUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "Help", new { Id = 46 })';
    console.log(videoHelpUrl);
</script>
```

console.log will output the Url.

Note: Always keep in mind that everything following @ in a Razor view will be processed by the Razor engine. This is why you can surround @Url.Action(...) with quotes. It will be processed first by Razor engine and then by Javascript when it is executed.

Comment: It was the quotes, definitely did not even notice they were missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you try using double {{ }} as in;

```
@{

    if (ViewData["showME"] != null && ViewData["showSuffix"] != null)
    {
        <text>
        showME = @(Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["showME"]) ? "true" : "false");
        showSuffix = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["showSuffix "]))';        
        </text>
    }

}
```

See if that works.

Comment: This is correct, my question was wrong.  My problem lies in this line..  thoughts?  var videoHelpUrl = @(Url.Action("Index", "Help", new { Id = 46 }));